# Applescript / Automator - Pass variables between them

Tags: applescript, automator, script

I have a question about how to pass the applescript input from one computer to another computer's automator input (I created it as a program). I've created the script below to ask for the filename and call the automator script on the target machine. Obviously I should be able to get ret of the dialog and set value of variable steps but just need some help in passing the variable to the second applescript section.

Applescript input -

```
tell application "Finder"
    display dialog "Please name the file with a unique data e.g. FocusGroup-01012014" default answer ""
    set myName to text returned of result
end tell

tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://username:password@ipaddress"
        open "Boardroom MacMini:Applications:Stop Recording"
end tell
```

Automator script - 
[image: automator]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you attempt to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than throwing your entire code at us?

Comment: I just need to collect a text response variable from a dialogue in an applescript and need to know how to call an automator script (on another machine) and pass in the variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a variable (folder pathway) to AppleScript in Automator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278469/pass-a-variable-folder-pathway-to-applescript-in-automator)