# How to pass two variables from previous actions to "run applescript" in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

What I'm trying to is:

1. Receive a string from "Ask for Text".
2. Get a file from Finder.
3. Do some codings these inputs in Applescript.

Seems like Applescript only receives file as input, I have no idea how to pass string from step 1 to it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

note: all "ignore action's input" are uncheck.

The workflow looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Try this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/278497/12285

Comment: You've set up the workflow correctly, you just need to process the `input` variable in AppleScript more attentively.  If you get rid of your current script and just executed the line `return input`, then hopefully, you will see the _Finder_ item **and** `Variable_1`'s text value sitting together in an array.  That being the case, you can access them using `item 1 of input` and `item 2 of input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my normal usage, typically when using a **Set Value of Variable** *action*, the subsequent *action* will have the **[√] Ignore this action's input** checkbox checked. This is because one does not typically set a *variable* and then pass it directly to the next *action*, unless of course the *value* of that *variable* will also be needed elsewhere in the *workflow* and the next *action* also makes use of the *variable*. Since a **Ask for Finder Items** *action* in your use case as shown in your question isn't going to use the *variable*, I've checked the **[√] Ignore this action's input** checkbox checked, in the **Ask for Finder Items** *action*. Of course adjust to your needs.

Now to pass both what's returned by the **Ask for Finder Items** *action* and the *value* of the `Variable_1` *variable*, place a **Get Value of Variable** *action* between the **Ask for Finder Items** *action* and the **Run AppleScript** **action**.

Then in this case, `input` in `on run {input, parameters}` is a list of two items, the first being what was passed from the **Ask for Finder Items** *action* and the second being the *value* of the `Variable_1` *variable* from the **Get Value of Variable** *action*, and here's an example **AppleScript** *code* addressing what is shown in your **Run AppleScript** **action** to handle it:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set filePath to the POSIX path of item 1 of input
    set Answer to item 2 of input   -- This is the value of the Variable_1 variable.

    return filePath & Answer
end run
```

That said, the `return` line may not be practical as it's just concatenating two strings at that point, so I suspect this is just for testing to see that it actually can return the two pieces of information.